# scaleQuantize, color bars based on height

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

I have a demo here

https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-pjt62p?file=src%2Fapp%2Fbar-chart.ts

It a D3 bar chart in an Angular app.

I want to change the color of the bars based on there height.

I'm tryin to use d3.scaleQuantize() to do this.

```
this.q_scale = d3.scaleQuantize()
  .domain([ 600, 1000, d3.max( data, (d) => d.value) ])
  .range(['blue', 'green', 'red']);
```

I am passing the colors in the range and I thought the domain would use these colors.

Something bars less than 600 would be blue, bars more then 600 but less than 1000 would green and bars over 1000 would be red.

Is d3.scaleQuantize() the correct way to do this.

If so what am I doing wrong

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnChanges, SimpleChanges, SimpleChange, ViewChild, HostListener } from "@angular/core";
import * as d3 from 'd3';

interface FLChart{
  date: string,
    value: number
}

@Component({
  selector: 'bar-chart',
  templateUrl: './bar-chart.html'
})

export class StackedChartCompoent {
  @Input() data: FLChart[];

  private margin = { top: 40, right: 20, bottom: 50, left: 40 };
  private w: number;
  private h: number = 400;
  private width: number;  
  private height = this.h - this.margin.top - this.margin.bottom;

  private x: any;
  private y: any;
  private y_axis: any;
  private x_axis: any;
  private svg: any;
  private g: any;
  private chart: any;
  private tooltip: any;
  private xAxis:any
  private yAxis:any
  private xScale:any
  private yScale:any
  private color:any

  private resizeTimeout: any;

  private qDomain = [500, 1000, 1500];
  private qRange = ['blue', 'green', 'red']

  @ViewChild('chartContainer')elementView: ElementRef;

    @HostListener('window:resize')
    onWindowResize() {

        if (this.resizeTimeout) {
            clearTimeout(this.resizeTimeout);
        }
        this.resizeTimeout = setTimeout((() => {
            this.w = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
            this.width = this.w - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;

            this.initScales();
            this.createAxis();
            this.drawUpdate(this.data);

        }).bind(this), 10);

    }

  constructor(private container: ElementRef) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.w = this.elementView.nativeElement.offsetWidth;
        this.width = this.w - this.margin.left - this.margin.right;
    this.initScales();
    this.initSvg();
    this.createAxis();
    this.drawUpdate(this.data);
  }

//----------------------- initScales

  private initScales() {
    this.x = d3.scaleBand()
      .range([0, this.width])
      .padding(.15)

    this.y = d3.scaleLinear()  
      .rangeRound([this.height, 0]);

  }

//----------------------- initSvg

  private initSvg() {

    this.svg = d3.select(this.container.nativeElement)
      .select('.chart-container')
      .append('svg')


    this.chart = this.svg.append('g')
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + this.margin.left + "," + this.margin.top + ")")  
  }

  private createAxis(){
        this.y_axis = d3.axisLeft(this.y)
                .tickPadding(10)
                .ticks(10)

        this.x_axis = d3.axisBottom(this.x)
                .scale(this.x)
                .tickPadding(10);

        this.chart.append("g").classed('y-axis', true);
        this.chart.append("g").classed('x-axis', true);
    }

//----------------------- drawUpdate

  private drawUpdate(data){
    this.x.domain(data.map( (d) => d.date) );

    this.y.domain([0, d3.max( data, (d) => d.value) ]);

    this.color = d3.scaleThreshold()
      .domain([600, 800])
      .range(['blue', 'green', 'red']); 

    const bar = this.chart.selectAll(".bar")
      .data(data)

      ///Enter
      bar.enter()
        .append("rect")
        .classed('bar', true)
        .attr('x', (d) => this.x(d.date))
        .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.value))
        .attr("height", (d) => this.height - this.y(d.value))
        .attr('fill', (d) => {
          return this.color(d)
        });

      bar
        .attr('x', (d) => this.x(d.date))
        .attr("width", this.x.bandwidth())
        .attr("y", (d) => this.y(d.value))
        .attr("height", (d) => this.height - this.y(d.value))
        .style('fill', (d) => {
          return this.color(d)
        })
      bar.exit()
        .remove()  

      d3.select('.y-axis')
        .transition()
        .call(this.y_axis)
        .selectAll(".tick text")

      d3.select('.x-axis')
        .call(this.x_axis)
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + this.height + ")")
        .selectAll(".tick text")   
        };


}
```

Comment: I would use a [threshold](https://github.com/d3/d3-scale#threshold-scales) scale which is intended to map continuous data into arbitrarily sized bins. Using your code block, the other change is that you don't need the max value in your domain (the domain has one less entry than the range: for example: in a two element (threshold) domain, there are three values for the range: one for under the lower threshold, one between the two thresholds, and one for over the upper threshold)

Comment: Using threshold and removing the domain value, I'm still seeing one color on the bars

Comment: Hi - you may need to share the code where the scale called to set the colour, or better still an example of the complete code in a snippet

Comment: I have updated the question with the complete code

Comment: you are passing d to the colour function, rather than d.value?

Answer (score 1):

On top of the two comments already provided (use a threshold scale; pass `d.values` to the scale), you have a problem with the meaning of `this`.

Inside the callback, `this` is the element itself. So, this:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){ 
    return this.q_scale(d.value)
});
```

Makes no sense, because the scale (`q_scale`) is not a method of the element.

That being said, use an arrow function:

```
.attr("fill", (d) => this.q_scale(d.value));
```

Or bind a different `this`:

```
.attr("fill", function(d){ 
    return this.q_scale(d.value)
}.bind(this));
```

Here is your code with those changes: https://stackblitz.com/edit/basic-bar-mt-zehzcv?file=src/app/bar-chart.ts